# Having the first letter F in uppercase in cross-reference to a 'figure' object

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I want the first letter of the paragraph to be in uppercase.

Suppose that we have this sentence:

```
\cref{fig:moon} shows the color of the moon.
```

I want the output to look like this:

> Fig. 1 shows the color of the moon.

Not like:

> fig. 1 shows the color of the moon.

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.250]{moon color}
\captionof{figure}{Color of the moon} 
\label{fig:moon}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Do you want that option globally or just for that case?

Comment: Doesn't `\Cref{fig:moon}` do the job?

Comment: No because I want to maintain the Fig.1 in blue color as it's used in elsevier latex . Also, I want to apply this MAJ option only for some Fig not for all figs and when I used \cref{fig:moon} we get Figure and I want Fig not Figure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an answer by @Werner to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31239637/5853002). Since this is on stackoverflow and not here in Tex.SX, I shamelessly cite his answer, happy to delete it if someone manages to import this question to make it a duplicate:

> This is clearly outlines in the
>   [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref)
>   [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf).
>
> You can either use `\Cref`, or pass the package option `capitalise`:
>
> [image]
>
> ```
> \documentclass{ieeetran}
> \usepackage{hyperref}
> \usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
> \begin{document}
> See \cref{fig:myfigure} or \Cref{fig:myfigure}.
> \begin{figure}
>   \caption{Some figure}\label{fig:myfigure}
> \end{figure}
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> If you wish to customize the way `\Cref` prints (output `Fig.` rather
>   than `Figure`), add
>
> ```
> \Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}% {<type>}{<singular>}{<plural>}
> ```

Comment: In fact there are two problems here : the first one when I capitalise I don't have the Fig.1 in blue color as it should be in elsevier template the second problem is when I capitalise all Figs are capitalised and I don't want this I want to capitalise only some Figs

Comment: @kerdoujkardouj Then you just have to change the creflabelformat as described in the package's documentation.